# Resources similar to "Russian for the Mathematician" in other languages?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-french, mathematical-german, mathematical-russian

I had recently come across "Russian for the Mathematician" by S.H. Gould, and saw it as a wonderfully useful resource. I have very little experience in Russian (only skill is ability to read Cyrillic), but I saw it as a useful introduction to the language, in the sense that I would be able to decipher Russian language math literature without the need to be entirely fluent or understand every word. Reading through a preview, I like how it breaks apart the words piece by piece to I was wondering if there were any resources for other languages in this similar vein, e.g. learning French or German with the main focus of reading scientific or mathematical literature.

Downloadable [here](https://zlib.pub/download/russian-for-the-mathematician-6rmcqd6u9b00?hash=5ec722672f4eb4d1b8b19efb314eaef3)

Comment: See https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27580/learning-german-from-scratch-in-order-to-read-mathematics#28169 for some recomm's, but note Gould's intention was specificly a linguist's, whereas here you'll find math-oriented sources. The dictionary is great though. Anyway, perhaps ask in french.SE for theirs